# Is there a way for a Javascript Discord Bot to send a DM to a specific person?

Tags: javascript, discord, bots

I am trying to create a system that allows a user to send a message and receive a DM from a bot. That part is working fine. However, I also want the bot to send a message to myself when that happens. Whenever I try to get it to send a message to me, it will always have an error.

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.toString().toLowerCase().includes('support')) {
        message.author.send('Your assistance ticket has been created. Please wait for a DM from ageekdude.')
    message.ageekdude.send(message.author + ' has requested an assistance ticket.')
    }
});

client.login('token here');
```

At the part where it says message.ageekdude.send, I'm trying to get it to send that message to me. Also, at the part where it says message.author, could you tell me how to make it say the name of the user instead of the user ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
if (message.toString().toLowerCase().includes('support')) {
    message.author.send('Your assistance ticket has been created. Please wait for a DM from ageekdude.');
    const ageekdude = client.users.cache.get('PASTE YOUR USER ID HERE');
    if (ageekdude) ageekdude.send(message.author + ' has requested an assistance ticket.')
}
```

This will try to find you in the list of all bot's users, and then send you the message,
I hope this will solve your issue !